# Reassign variables in if/else (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

How can I achieve a reassigned list (or any other value for that matter) in javascript?

I've tried to do as I'd do in python, and make a empty list and assign it if my conditions are met, but it seems that javascript will fall right back on what's assigned out of my `if/else`

My goal is to achieve something like this:

```
let data1 = [];
let data2 = [];
let data3 = [];
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  if (document.getElementById('minus').checked) {
    let data1 = [-64, 31, 23, 34, 23, 30, 50, 43, 29, 64, 22, 34];
    let data2 = [-23, 45, 83, 74, 99, 83, 64, 72, 50, 44, 36, 45];
    let data3 = [-64, 75, 43, 24, 63, 72, 88, 24, 84, 93, 45, 60];
  } else {
    let data1 = [64, 31, 23, 34, 23, 30, 50, 43, 29, 64, 22, 34];
    let data2 = [23, 45, 83, 74, 99, 83, 64, 72, 50, 44, 36, 45];
    let data3 = [64, 75, 43, 24, 63, 72, 88, 24, 84, 93, 45, 60];
  }
});

//Further code that uses the variables we just set
```

fiddle on my issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/vk8swjc3/

Comment: If you `let x` inside a block, you're creating a new variable `x` in the inner scope. Remove `let` and you're reassigning the original `x`.

Comment: are you trying to set content only after the first load? or after the checkbox changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently redefining all of those data variables by saying let again. Remove the lets and do `data1 = [-64, 31, 23, 34, 23, 30, 50, 43, 29, 64, 22, 34]` directly to reassign them.

Comment: I've updated my post with a fiddle, it does not seem to work, but it makes perfectly sense.

Comment: Ah yeah, looks like you might be trying to access the data from data1, data2, data3 etc. before the event listener you have set up has run. Move the rest of your code inside of that event listener and you should be able to access the data - also if you console.log data1 shortly after the if/else statement, you should see the array filled with 12 items as you're expecting to see.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. If you use `let x` inside a block, you're creating a new variable `x` in the inner scope. Remove `let` and you're reassigning the original `x`.
2. If you reassign them inside a `DOMContentLoaded` callback, the new values won't be available to the immediately running code after you set up that callback (only in the callback itself, or once the callback has run). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Here's a demo of the order of execution:

```js
console.log('top')

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded')

  executeWithinCallback()
})

const executeWithinCallback = () => {
  console.log('after DOMContentLoaded')
}

console.log('bottom')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are use `var`, `let` or `const` on a scope(curly braces) you are defined a variable that you can use only inside of that scope.

So if you want to use top level variable in another scope then you shouldn't use `var`, `let` or `const` to assign a value to variable.

You can look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 1):

Having addressed the variable scoping issues that you had in your initial post we can now look at the larger part of your question which seems to be the matter of changing data, or at least setting initial data based on the state of a control.

Your fiddle is working as intended, but not as you expect it to. If you `console.log()` any of the data arrays after the conditional within the `DOMContentLoaded` you will see the updated array.

```
let data1 = [];
let data2 = [];
let data3 = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  if (document.getElementById('minus').checked) {
    data1 = [-64, 31, 23, 34, 23, 30, 50, 43, 29, 64, 22, 34];
    data2 = [-23, 45, 83, 74, 99, 83, 64, 72, 50, 44, 36, 45];
    data3 = [-64, 75, 43, 24, 63, 72, 88, 24, 84, 93, 45, 60];
  } else {
    data1 = [64, 31, 23, 34, 23, 30, 50, 43, 29, 64, 22, 34];
    data2 = [23, 45, 83, 74, 99, 83, 64, 72, 50, 44, 36, 45];
    data3 = [64, 75, 43, 24, 63, 72, 88, 24, 84, 93, 45, 60];
  }
  console.log(data1);
});
// [64, 31, 23, 34, 23, 30, 50, 43, 29, 64, 22, 34]
```

However, by the time that runs you have already set up your chart with the empty array values and it has rendered. Changing the values of the data arrays after that will have no effect on the rendered chart, nor on the values of the arrays assigned to `chartData.datasets[n].data`

In order to update the chart you need to change these dataset values and call `update` on the the chart.

```
let barVertical = document.getElementById("barVertical");
let barVerticalChart = new Chart(barVertical, {
    type: "bar",
    data: chartData,
    options: chartOptions,
});

const minus =  document.getElementById('minus');
minus.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    chartData.datasets[0].data = [-64, 31, 23, 34, 23, 30, 50, 43, 29, 64, 22, 34];
    chartData.datasets[1].data = [-23, 45, 83, 74, 99, 83, 64, 72, 50, 44, 36, 45];
    chartData.datasets[2].data = [-64, 75, 43, 24, 63, 72, 88, 24, 84, 93, 45, 60];
  } else {
    chartData.datasets[0].data = [64, 31, 23, 34, 23, 30, 50, 43, 29, 64, 22, 34];
    chartData.datasets[1].data = [23, 45, 83, 74, 99, 83, 64, 72, 50, 44, 36, 45];
    chartData.datasets[2].data = [64, 75, 43, 24, 63, 72, 88, 24, 84, 93, 45, 60];
  }
  barVerticalChart.update();
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3tmon21/

---

Or, to simply make your code run as you seem to expect, using the conditionally set arrays on the first render, simply move all the code that comes after it into the `DOMContentLoaded` listener.

```
let data1 = [];
let data2 = [];
let data3 = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  if (document.getElementById('minus').checked) {
    data1 = [-64, 31, 23, 34, 23, 30, 50, 43, 29, 64, 22, 34];
        data2 = [-23, 45, 83, 74, 99, 83, 64, 72, 50, 44, 36, 45];
        data3 = [-64, 75, 43, 24, 63, 72, 88, 24, 84, 93, 45, 60];
  } else {
    data1 = [64, 31, 23, 34, 23, 30, 50, 43, 29, 64, 22, 34];
        data2 = [23, 45, 83, 74, 99, 83, 64, 72, 50, 44, 36, 45];
        data3 = [64, 75, 43, 24, 63, 72, 88, 24, 84, 93, 45, 60];
  }

  let labels = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    let chartData = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Data1",
            data: data1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(154, 18, 179, .7)",
        },
        {
            label: "Data2",
            data: data2,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(232, 126, 4, .7)",
        },
        {
            label: "Data3",
            data: data3,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 230, 64, .7)",
        },
    ],
    };


    let barVertical = document.getElementById("barVertical");
    let barVerticalChart = new Chart(barVertical, {
    type: "bar",
    data: chartData,
    options: chartOptions,
  });
});
```